# Safari html5 video timeupdate event gets disabled

Tags: safari, html5-video

We are playing videos from a server.  We attach an 'ontimeupdate' event which fires periodically, as the video plays.  For slow connections, we can compare where the video currently IS, to where it SHOULD be.  Then we can do some other things we need to do, if it is lagging.  Everything works fine in Chrome, FF, IE. In Safari, when the connection is slow, the event only fires twice.  Why does it get removed?  Is there a way to add the event again, inside of the handler for the event?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 audio/video element is still less than perfect.  The biggest issues I've noticed is that it doesn't always behave the same way in every browser.  I do not know why the timeupdate event stops firing in Safari, but one option you have is to monitor whether the video is playing or not and verifying the information independently.  Example,

```
$(video).bind('play', function() {
    playing = true;
}).bind('pause', function() {
    playing = false;
}).bind('ended', function() {
    playing = false;
})

function yourCheck() {
    if (playing) {
        if (video.currentTime != timeItShouldBe) {
            //do something
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout( yourCheck(), 100);
}
```

Something to that effect.  Its not perfect, but neither is the current HTML5 audio/video element.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the code, will give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

The event will not fire if the `currentTime` does not change, so it may not be firing if the video has stopped playing to buffer. However, there are other events you can listen for:

1) "stalled" - browser is trying to load the video file, but it's not getting anything from the network.

2) "waiting" - playback has stopped because you ran out of buffered data, but it will probably pick up again once more data comes in from the network. This is probably the most useful one for you.

3) "playing" - playback has resumed. Not to be confused with "play" which just means it's "trying" to play. This event fires when the video is *actually* playing.

4) "progress" - browser got more data from the network. Sometimes just fires every so often, but it can also fire after it recovers from the "stalled" state.

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#mediaevents) for reference.

I've heard some people say that these events can be unreliable in some browsers, but they seem to be working just fine here: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

If you want to be extra cautious, you can also poll periodically (with a timeout as tpdietz wrote) and check the state of the video. The `readyState` property will tell you whether you have enough data to show the current frame ( >= 2 ), enough to keep playing at least a little bit into the future ( >= 3 ) or enough to play all the way to the end (probably). You can also use the `buffered` property to see how much of the video has actually been buffered ahead of where you're playing, so you can roughly estimate the data rate (if you know how big the file is).

MDN has a [great reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) on all these properties and events.